# Visual Studio Code Noob - Where does config go?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Total noob question, sorry.

Whenever I've tried to use VS Code, I often install an extension and then I can't "find" it. It doesn't add menu options or seem to do anything, most are like this, so clearly its me being thick.

The extension Readmes often talk about adding settings and yet I can't figure out where to add them.

Example:

[image: Readme for an extension]

I can't see any window or UI control for this Test Explorer, though its apparently installed.

It says to set that `dotnet-test-explorer.testProjectPath` setting but I have no idea where that settings file is.

Is it a global file or something I add to my project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! Both things hiding themselves in strange places (IMO).

The Test Explorer is right down there!

And I also found the settings. That's under File > Preferences > Settings, and it seems that you don't edit the file, but copy an override into a JSON file on the right.

[image: UI control]

Comment: Was going to show you how to do it but you figured it out.  BTW, a quick trick to change the settings is point to the settings you want (on the left panel) and you should see a pencil icon shows up.  That is the way you can tweak the settings and see all the options, and then you can pick the value you like and it will be copied over to your personal settings.

Comment: Cheers Ian. Some 'funny' nuances to learn. I didn't expect a Preferences GUI menu to open a text file and I was expecting new GUI elements to appear up the top alongside the others, not tucked away down there. I see there's a gear icon down there now, too haha. I have a massive 2560px screen.

Comment: Wow, nice to have that screen.  VSCode is definitely an awesome IDE to use and there are many YouTube tutorials that worth a quick look, and that is how I learned the cool features about it.

Comment: I was going through the same situation, thanks a lot!